# How to make the Yun allow access to a resource

Tags: arduino-yun, web-server

I have replaced /www folder on the Yun (backing it up first), how do I make it so the Yun will redirect to the new index.html? It, right now, gives `Access to this resource is forbidden` when I go to *yun-name-here*.local

Edit: I guess it's relevent to add I can do it fine with *yun-name-here*.local/index.html meaning it works. The real question is how to make it so I don't need to type /index.html (HURRAY LAZINESS!)

Edit II: It's [Kittens game](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/)

Comment: Did you try editing the web server configuration?

Comment: web server config?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think I borked it... I replaced /etc/config/uttpd with it's backup after modifying and now I can't connect

Comment: fixed the borkedness

Comment: Which web server did you install on it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams _manly face_ Kittens Game _manly face fail_

Comment: That sounds like a web application, not a web server.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's both. I downloaded it from the [git repository](https://bitbucket.org/bloodrizer/kitten-game), and moved it to /www directory

Comment: Nothing in that repository is a web server.

Comment: The question still stands, though